# Can't get any smooth scrolling script to work

Tags: html, scroll, smoothing

I have now tried about 6 different "smooth scrolling" scripts on my site and none of them have done anything.

What I have is a single-page portfolio (not finished yet) that has three links at the top that link to the various sections of the page using named anchors. When you click one of the top links I want it to scroll smoothly to the section so you can see it scrolling over everything it is passing by.

I have tried a handful of scripts found on google and also a couple that are wordpress plugins but none of them do ANYTHING. What am I doing wrong? Right now if you take a look at my site I currently have two scripts being included and neither are working. One is a wordpress plugin and the other is a small bit of code found of Google.

www.johnwhancock.com (note that only the Portfolio link is setup at this moment)

Some of the scripts I have tried (don't remember what the first ones were) is:

- The "Easy Smooth Scroll Links" wordpress plugin (currently active),
- The "Page Scroll to id" plugin
- The short script shown on http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?s=2a9d6c624c48b13a2bc824af5e44bfb5&p=208163&postcount=2
- This script: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

and a few others I don't have the link for anymore. None of them worked. Thank you.

Comment: Try to include your non-functioning code here. Pointing us to a website is not sustainable when you will ultimately fix it. The questions you ask here should not only be useful to you, but to future visitors as well.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my original post to reflect some of the things I tried. As far as I know I used them all correctly. I usually don't have a problem adding scripts like these to a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not exactly clear on what you've tried so far. If you've found code by googling please also paste it hear so we can see what you're trying to accomplish.
I assume you're meant to use the "smooth scrolling" effect for your slideshow.
1. Try looking at the code for some of the wordpress themes already built for this purpose.
2. Try searching for some JQuery code snippets.

**Edit:**
The second link shows a legitimate piece of code. There might be some problems with JQuery being loaded. Try this to make sure you have JQuery script loaded on the page:

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
alert("READY!");
});
```

this should show an alert after the page is loaded. If the alert is not shown, then JQuery is not properly loaded. I assume that's the problem because the code looks fine.

Comment: Got it! You were right, jquery wasn't being loaded correctly. I found a wordpress plugin that makes sure the latest stable version of jquery is used, and that fixed it. I am now using the "Page scroll to Id" plugin without issue.

Comment: Whoops, guess it wasn't the plugin that was working (it doesn't seem to). It was the code found on http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/ that eventually worked. Thanks again.